# Joint distribution of sum of dependent Poisson distributions

Tags: self-learning

We have three independently Poisson distributed random variables, $U, V, W$, with intensities $\lambda, \mu, \nu$. Now, define $X = U + W$, and $Y = V + W$. The task is now to find the joint pmf of $(X, Y)$. What I started doing was the following:
\begin{equation}
  P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = \sum_i \sum_j P(X = i, Y = j) = \sum_i \sum_j P(U + W = i, V + W = j),
\end{equation}
but as they are not independent, I'm not really sure on how to continue. Any pointers?

**Edit**
As someone seems to have downvoted I'm guessing it's for lack of trying. As such, my continued try resulted in
\begin{equation}
\sum_i \sum_j P(U + W = i, V + W = j) = \\ \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k P(U + W = i, V + W = j \mid W = k)P(W = k) = \\ \sum_i \sum_j \sum_k P(U = i - k, V = j - k)P(W = k).
\end{equation}
But still not sure at all, that this is even remotely correct.

Comment: you're almost there. remove sums on $i$ and $j$ else you'll just be proving $1 = 1$. Split the last sum into two as $U$ and $V$ are independent. Let me know if you're still not able to finish

Comment: also what you're calculating above is the CDF which is clearly not needed. The statement $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = \sum_i \sum_j P(X = i, Y = j)$ is not true. RHS is $1$, LHS is not

Comment: You're comment really helped, I think I'm onto something. And sorry, the sums are from $i = 0$ to $x$ and vice versa. But as you say, not really needed to consider the CDF

Comment: okay great, let me know if you can find the PMF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint PMF is
\begin{align}
P(U+W = i, V+W = j) &= \sum_k P(U+W=i,V+W=j∣W=k)P(W=k) \\ &= \sum_k P(U=i−k,V=j−k)P(W=k) \\ &= \sum_k P(U=i−k)P(V=j−k)P(W=k) \\ &= \sum_k \frac{e^\lambda \lambda^{i-k}}{(i-k)!}\frac{e^\mu\mu^{j-k}}{(j-k)!}\frac{e^\nu \nu^{k}}{k!}
\end{align}
Use the fact $k \leq i, k\leq j \implies k \leq \min\{i, j\}$ to rewrite the sum as
\begin{align}
P(U+W = i, V+W = j)&=e^{\lambda+\mu+\nu}\lambda^i\mu^j\sum_{k=1}^{\min\{i, j\}}\frac{\lambda^{-k}\mu^{-k}\nu^{k}}{(i-k)!(j-k)!k!}
\end{align}